# Is it possible to save Stack<Stack<View>> in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to save `Stack<Stack<View>>` in `onSaveInstanceState`.

May some another way how to save some specific data to manage Activity state?

Answer (score 1):

You can't save views to bundle. And you shouldn't do it anyway. If activity is recreated it will reinflate layout again (or even inflate another one if configuration has changed) and create a new view hierarchy.

You should separate business data from your UI and store it onSaveInstanceState. After activity recreation you should get that data and update new views hierarchy accordingly.

For example, if you have a TextView, that displays some text that is stored in a field mSuperText, and your activity is going down, you should save it into a bundle in onSaveInstanceState:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("supertext", mSuperText);
}
```

And when your activity is recreated, in your method onCreate you get an argument onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) which will be the bundle you stored previously. So you can get values you need:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         mSuperText = savedInstanceState.getString("superText");
    }
}
```

Comment: May be I ask incorrect. Try to explain: I have one Activity to whole project. And multiple views, witch store in stack. I show to user only last view in stack. When user want "go back", I remove last view from stack, and show nested. Problem is - I cant store current position, where is user in app. I can just recreate whole activity and clean stack.

Comment: Views are tied to context (which is your activity instance). Since activity gets destroyed your views should too. Consider using fragments, they will make your task easier and their life cycle is more flexible than that of the views

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to save Stack> in onSaveInstanceState.

No, because Stack and View doesn't have the Parcelable / Serializable interface, which is necessary to put an Object in a Bundle. A Bundle only takes Arrays/ArrayList, String, primitives and so on.

> May some another way how to save some specific data to manage Activity
>   state?

Which data you wanna save? If you wanna save a whole View/ViewGroup you are probably on the wrong way.

E.g to indicate that a TextView was visible set a boolean to true and put it in the Bundle. Check the boolean in onCreate() and set the View to visible. If the TextView had some text too, save it as String and set the text to the TextView, which you made visible.